# Unexpected behaviour from pst-arrow

Tags: pstricks, pst-arrow

Consider the following example.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-arrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psset{
  doublesep = 0.5cm,
  fillstyle = solid,
  fillcolor = blue!80!white
}
  \psBigArrow(3.5,3)(0,3)
  \psBigArrow(4,3)(7.5,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Question**

Why are the two arrows not vertically aligned?

Comment: That looks like a bug. I'll investigate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the version from [http://tug.org/~hvoss/pst-arrow.tex](http://tug.org/%7Ehvoss/pst-arrow.tex) it works well:

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

If you draw in the axis

[image]

Then it looks more reasonable as it is rotated through 180 degrees but was not symmetric around the axis.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-arrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psset{
  doublesep = 0.5cm,
  fillstyle = solid,
  fillcolor = blue!80!white
}
  \psBigArrow(3.5,3)(0,3)
  \psBigArrow(4,3)(7.5,3)

  
  \psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red](0,3)(10,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Arrrh! I see. Can I somehow alignet the two arrows automatically?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg (a) yes, must be possible to rotate around a different point (b) I last really used pstricks in 1994 so you may be able to scan the manual quicker than I can:-)

Comment: or of course you could draw both arrows in same direction then reflect (rather than rotate) one of them to point the other way @SvendTveskæg